# How to determine if java function executed successfully

Tags: java, error-handling, return, pass-by-value

In c++, I'd usually pass a byRef variable as a parameter to the function to get the information that I need returned, and I'd return a boolean or int value from the function to determine if the function was executed successfully (no errors occurred at any point).

I can't do that in Java since you can only pass byVal, and can get one thing returned.

I guess you can return some array or list, but I feel like that's bad coding practice.

What are some proper ways to deal with this problem?

Comment: How about exception handling? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

Comment: what else are you returning ?

Comment: objects, and doing only one thing in a function is the right way

Comment: standard practice is definitely "throw an exception on failure, otherwise assume success"

Comment: You can simulate byref parameters by passing a mutable container. But the more conventional approach would be to either throw an exception, as suggested above, or return a wrapper object that encapsulates whatever additional information you need.

Comment: You can define return type Object and later you can cast it either in int or boolean

Comment: @Ravi I'm returning a string in this case, but I'm asking more in a general coding practice kind of sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it exactly like in c++, you can pass a primitive by reference via its wrapper-class (e.g. class `Integer` for primitive `int`). But I agree with the comments below the question that the 'proper way' of doing this in Java is to throw an exception in case of failure. In case you do not like both ideas, you can still use static variables in the class that implements the method you are executing, let them be set by that method and read by the invoking method/class, but this is no good coding practice either and should not be done unless there is no other option for whatever reasons.